After a lot of searching we have enabled autoplay with voice onscroll on our website but there is a problem
After searching a lot, we started autoplay with sound on our website but there is a problem that whenever the video comes inside the viewport, it starts automatically but when another video comes in the viewport, the above video should stop. Both videos play at the same time as long as both remain within the viewport.
This my code:
HTML:
<video 
id="video--<?php echo $wo['media']['storyId'];?>" 
class="plyrr-<?php echo $wo['media']['storyId'].$rand ; ?> <?php echo($wo['rvad_con']); ?> video-container" 
playsinline preload="metadata" 
poster="<?php  echo $wo['media']['video_thumb'];?>" 
data-setup="{}" data-post-video="<?php echo $wo['media']['storyId'];?>"
>

JavaScript (JQuery):
$(window).scroll(function(e)
{
    if (!document.pictureInPictureElement) 
    {
        $('.plyrr-<?php echo $wo['media']['storyId'].$rand ; ?>').each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) 
            { jQuery(this).get(0).play(); } 
            else 
            { $(this)[0].pause();  }
        });
    }
});

Problem:
It's not working like Instagram or Facebook where only one video plays at a time.
Is it possible to adjust Viewport size (or such) if the two videos are inside viewport at same time? How to stop the first video and play the second (latest video into viewport after scrolling up or down)?

example image of problem. The two video play at same time

Please check my example HTML page at: https://pintrafeed.com/directory



(1) I don't use JQuery (only regular JS) so while you wait for a JQuery answer, just consider this other Question about X/Y positions. Might be useful towards ideas to solve it.

(2) Try to use the video tag ID's to your advantage. Maybe have a variable like current_playing_id and whenever a new video is in the viewport , use an IF statement to first pause/stop the "current" one and then update current_playing_id var to make this other new video ID as the new "current" one to play. (3) If two videos are in viewport, use their Y position to know how central (compared to the screen) they are. The ID with most nearest Y to the "screen centre" should be the "current" to play.

Thanks for commenting.. can you make my code in X/Y position I can copy and paste the script section... I am already use many multiple methods for it but not succeess

After many research and change mathods finely I got this answer
I have changed in my
jQuery( JavaScript )
if ($(this).is(":in-viewport(250)")) 

Now one video play at a time in the viewport
